# VirtualBox 4.0.2 Map XP Host C:\ with Ubuntu 10.10 guest

Tags: virtualbox, network-shares, ubuntu-10.10

I'm using VirtualBox 4.0.2 with Ubuntu 10.10 as a guest.  I'm trying to map my Windows XP `C:\` drive under the guest to share documents.  I can map a server by going to Places --> Connect to Server... and following the prompt for Windows Share.  I was hoping there would be an easy way to map my Host C:\ the same way...i.e.:

Places --> Connect to Server

Service type: Windows Share

Server: `[computer name]`

Share: `C$`

Username: `[username]`

DomainName: `[domain]`

Then Connect

But that doesn't work...

Answer (score 2):

Have you set up shared folders and installed the vbox tools on the guest? It seems you're trying to access the host C: drive via the "normal" CIFS network share. It's much faster, and harder to break, if you go with shared folders instead:

http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=15868

> Boot the Guest and open a terminal.
>   Create a folder where you will mount
>   it on. E.g. in your home folder. I
>   will use `~/host` for the mount point.
>   Now mount it with the following
>   command:
>
> ```
> sudo mount -t vboxsf share ~/host
> ```
>
> Note that with this, the default mount
>   options are used and all files are
>   owned by root.
>
> This can be changed by adding some
>   mount options. Options are passed on
>   with the -o parameter. You can use
>   multiple options with one parameter,
>   seperate the values with a comma. See
>   the man page of mount for more info on
>   which options you can use. The User
>   Manual also notes the options
>   compatible with the Shared Folders. To
>   mount the SF so that you are the owner
>   of the files, use this command:
>
> ```
> sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=1000,gid=1000 share ~/host
> ```

Comment: Expanded answer is always better than plain links @DanielS